# As a library author, how do you provide paths to Web Workers inside your library?

Tags: javascript, html, path, web-worker

When instantiating a WebWorker, ie:

```
const worker = new Worker(path);
```

if `path` is relative, it is relative to the document – not relative to the script where this line is written.

As a library author in charge of a library that loads its own WebWorkers, how do you best expose to the end developer the ability to modify/prefix this path, so that they may load your library into any document?